# Codename one style does not display on android tablet

Tags: codenameone

I just developed a multiplatform mobile app with Codename One. I styled it using the codename one visual tool. I tested the app on multiple ios and Android devices and everything is fine except on asus android tablet. With these one. The screen displays like no style is loaded. The screens remains mainly dark... any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look within your override directory, if you have a file there just delete it.

Comment: It works Shai ! You rocks ! I really appreciate your fast and effective answer !